# Struct and pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, typedef

Need to setup an interface to be used like this and make it a .H file:

```
MY_INTERFACE * mip;
MY_BAR bar;
int Status;
InitMyInterface(&mip);
Status = mip->foo(&bar);
```

Where:

- `MY_BAR` is a typedef for a structure with two members, both of type int.
- `MY_FOO` (not listed directly in the example code) is a typedef for a function pointer for a function the takes a pointer to a structure typedef `MY_BAR` and returns an int.
- `MY_INTERFACE` is a typedef for a structure with one member, a function pointer of type `MY_FOO`.

and this is my code and i get this error `..\Q2\q2.c|26|error: called object is not a function or function pointer|`

```
typedef struct MY_BAR {
   int  V1;
   int  bar;
} MY_BAR;

typedef int (*MY_FOO)(MY_BAR bar);

typedef struct MY_INTERFACE {
   MY_FOO *foo;
} MY_INTERFACE;

int InitMyInterface(MY_INTERFACE **mip);

int main( )
{
    MY_INTERFACE * mip;
    MY_BAR bar;
    int Status;
    InitMyInterface(&mip);
    Status = mip->foo(&bar);
}
```

Comment: and which is line 26?

Comment: Status = mip->foo(&bar);

Answer (score 2):

This because you declare a `MY_FOO* foo` inside `MY_INTERFACE`, which is a pointer to a pointer of function, but `MY_FOO` is already a function pointer per se.

So the correct typedef should be:

```
typedef struct MY_INTERFACE {
   MY_FOO foo;
} MY_INTERFACE;
```

Unless you want to call it by dereferencing `(*mip->foo)(&bar)`, but it does't make sense since you don't need a pointer to pointer there.

In addition the typedef of the function is

```
typedef int (*MY_FOO)(MY_BAR bar);
```

but this accepts a `MY_BAR`, and you are invoking it with `&bar` which is a `MY_BAR*` so you should change the signature accordingly:

```
typedef int (*MY_FOO)(MY_BAR* bar);
```

Comment: thank you for the help i did those changes and i get this error 
..\Q2\q2.o:q2.c|| undefined reference to `InitMyInterface'|

Comment: That's a different story since there is no implementation for the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MY_BAR {
   int  V1;
   int  bar;
} MY_BAR;

typedef int (*MY_FOO)(MY_BAR *bar);

typedef struct MY_INTERFACE {
   MY_FOO  foo;
} MY_INTERFACE;

static int _MyFooFunction(MY_BAR *bar){
    return bar->bar*bar->V1;
}
int InitMyInterface(MY_INTERFACE **mip){
    if(*mip){
        *mip=malloc(sizeof(MY_INTERFACE));
        (*mip)->foo=_MyFooFunction;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(void )
{
    MY_INTERFACE * mip;
    MY_BAR bar={5,3};
    int Status;
    if(!InitMyInterface(&mip)){
        printf("failed to initialize mip\n");
        return 1;
    }
    Status = mip->foo(&bar);
    printf("Status=%d\n",Status);
    free(mip);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (you'll see the differences and what fixed it):
Notice that the function pointer typedef makes the argument a *pointer* to bar;

```
typedef struct myBar {
   int  v1Flag;
   int  bar;
} myBar_t;

typedef int (*myFoo_t)(myBar_t *bar);

typedef struct myInterface {
   myFoo_t foo;
} myInterface_t;

int InitMyInterface(myInterface_t **mip) {
   return 0;
}

int main( )
{
    myInterface_t *mip;
    myBar_t bar;
    InitMyInterface(&mip);
    int status = mip->foo(&bar);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help i did those changes and i get this error `..\Q2\q2.o:q2.c|| undefined reference to InitMyInterface'|`

Comment: That's because you don't have the code for it. You need to add that function definition to your code or put it in another file you link with that one.

Comment: @Charles See my changes in the code. I changed it from a function prototype (e.g. 'declaration') to a function *definition*... A *declaration* merely describes the function signature (arguments, return type), it but doesn't provide the body to the function that can actually be invoked. So it gives the compiler what it needs to form the nature of the call but doesn't satisfy the linker.

Comment: @Charles - Alternatively you could leave the function prototype (e.g. *declaration*) as you had and compile it with `cc -c myprog.c` which defers the linking phase until later, then link the resulting myprog.o  with an object file (?.o) you also compiled with -c, which does have the actual function *definition* in it.

Comment: @Charles - When you put a function definition in a separate file, usually there is a header file that has the function declaration (function 'prototype') in it that can be included in all of the files so they are all in agreement about the function interfaces (arguments and return value, etc...)